# Optimize Join sentence with foreign keys, and show records with nulls

Tags: mysql, join, null, foreign-keys

I have the following structure

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sis_param_tax` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `description` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sis_param_city` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sis_supplier` (
  `id` int(15) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `phone` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `fk_city` int(11) default NULL,
  `fk_tax` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `fk_city` (`fk_city`),
  KEY `fk_tax` (`fk_tax`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

ALTER TABLE `sis_supplier`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `sis_supplier_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_tax`) REFERENCES `sis_param_tax` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `sis_supplier_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_city`) REFERENCES `sis_param_city` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

***My questions are***

**1.** This structure allows me to have a supplier with city and tax fields = null (in case user didn't set these values). Right?

**2.** If I delete "X" city, supplier's fk_city with city="X" are set to null, same with fk_tax. Right?

**3.** I want to optimize (***IF POSSIBLE***) the following join sentence, so I can show suppliers whom have fk_city and/or fk_tax = NULL

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  sis_supplier.id,
  sis_supplier.name,
  sis_supplier.telefono,
  sis_supplier.address,
  sis_supplier.phone,
  sis_supplier.cuit,
  sis_param_city.name AS city,
  sis_param_tax.description AS tax,
  sis_supplier.fk_city,
  sis_supplier.fk_tax
FROM
  sis_supplier 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sis_param_city
  ON
  sis_supplier.`fk_city` = sis_param_city.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `sis_param_tax`
  ON
  sis_supplier.`fk_tax` = `sis_param_tax`.`id`
```

Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Yes.
3. Yes, it's good to optimize.  The query you showed looks fine.  How is it not working for you?

---

Have you analyzed the query with [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html)?  This can help you tell when you have a query that isn't using indexes effectively.  In fact, all of [Chapter 7 Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimization.html) would be recommended reading.

Comment: It is working fine, I just wanted to know if the query is already optimized, or if it could be more optimized...
In case it can be optimized, could you provide a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show records with nulls than use **RIGHT or LEFT JOIN**
depend on your needs